# POST Being werid

Tags: php

Why does Username work and password not? its spose to spit out what you type in the text boxes. Username works but password gives me an error.

```
 <form method = "POST">

    Username:<input type='text' name="username"><br>
    Password: <input type = 'password' name = "password"><br>
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Login' name= 'submit'>




    <?php



    $Ausername = "Adam";
    $Apassword = "abc";

    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);

    echo $username;
    echo $password;

    ?>

    </form>
```

Comment: Why do you wrap your $_POST variables in parenthesis?

Comment: I thought you had to it makes no difference tho.

Answer (score 3):

You're omitting a "=" following the name.

Should be:

```
  Password: <input type = 'password' name="password">
```

This works. If it doesn't work for you, I don't know what to say.

```
<form method="POST">
    Username: <input type='text' name="username"><br>
    Password: <input type='password' name="pw"><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Login' name='submit'>
</form>

<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pw'];

echo $username;
echo $password;

?>
```

Comment: You have `name "password"` when it needs to be `name="password"`. As is, you're currently not setting the name to anything.

Comment: Still arnt working :(

Comment: You are echoing unset values. Check to make sure they are actually set.

Comment: What do you mean they get set?

Comment: Copy and paste my updated answer into your code. It works. There's no way it does not work.

Comment: @user3196213 If this answer is correct, please at least mark it as accepted. 'Tis right netiquette.